# Do any browsers support Server Name Indication (SNI) but NOT SHA-2?

Tags: tls, openssl, chrome, sha256

Yes, I know that SHA-2 signature validation is typically done by the operating system (with Mozilla Firefox/NSS and Chrome as of v39 being the exception).

Comment: Can you add more explanation to your question? I can't quite figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Browsers that don't support SNI are: msie on winxp, java6, android2.3. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html

Comment: Minimum OS to support SHA256: WinXP SP3, Android 2.3, iOS 3, Mac OS X 10.5, Java 1.4.2.  https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility Basically, if a client can reach the non-default vhost on an IP, they can handle a sha256 cert. I don't know which clients CloudFlare has in mind that need sha1 certs.

Answer (score 2):

## Chrome on XP SP2?

*(Disclaimer: Conjecture follows.)*

XP SP2 lacks the [SHA2 capabilities that XP SP3 added](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968730).

- IE8 can't SNI. -> so it's out of the candidate list.
- IE9 can SNI. IE9 uses the OS-cert-mangement. But [IE9 doesn't run on XP.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/system-requirements)
- Firefox does it's own cert-management. And it has [supported SHA-2 for a long time.](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility). And it has also [supported SNI for a long time](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sni).
- Chrome uses the OS-level-cert-management. So it can only accept certs that the OS says are good. And if you run Win XP SP2 [(no SP3), as many Chinese supposedly do,](https://twitter.com/cryptoki/status/566747461041917952) then this might mean you're out of luck. (Note: [Google's support for Chrome on XP ends 2016-04.](http://chrome.blogspot.de/2015/11/updates-to-chrome-platform-support.html))

*(Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this.)*